# How to fully cancel changes due to installation of software that require complex procedures?

Tags: apt, software-recommendation, uninstall, backup

I have recently install from source a software (Odoo) that require a complex procedure to be installed: creation of new users, connection to servers etc. etc.

I want to install it again because it doesn't work but I can't start from zero because I am not able to understand how to remove all the changes applied to Ubuntu: new users, change in the setting etc. etc. of course `sudo apt-get uninstall` remove only packages so it won't work.

I wonder what is the best thing to do (back-up?) before I start to install software like that to be sure that if it doesn't work I can completely cancel the all changes due to the installation I was thinking to perform a back-up before installing software like that but I am not sure what is the best practice.

Comment: If you have installed it from source file and did not use `checkinstall` then you need to manually undo everything..also there is no command like `sudo apt-get uninstall` ..if you did not use `dpkg` to install any package, the package won't be in its database and hence can't be managed using `apt`/`dpkg`..

Comment: @heemayl thanks a lot,  please do you have any generic advice for the next time? Can you please answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have installed the package from source file you need to manually remove all the files inserted into the system by the package.

For future reference i would suggest you to install packages from official repositories. If for some reason you need to install from source always use `checkinstall` instead of `make install`.

`make install` simply copies file all over the system without any feasible method of tracking down them later, while using `checkinstall` the files that would be copied into the system is made as a package first by `checkinstall`. So `dpkg` can keep keep track of the files as they are under a package then hence while removing just `sudo dpkg -r package` will be enough to remove the package (and clean the files).

If `checkinstall` is not installed already, install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install checkinstall
```

Now the common installation procedure from source file can take the following form:

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Now `checkinstall` will in turn call `make install` and will make a package out of the files first.

Comment: +1 thanks, of course it can't reverse the changes regarding new user or server settings right? A back up is not recommended?

Comment: @GM No ....it will simple deal with the package in hand..it won't change any setting or anything..but if you have something that depends on this package that will be broken as you can imagine....no backup is required IMO..also be sure to install from authentic source..